# Colors incorrect on first execution of code

Tags: r, colors

I have a code that plots several stacked bar charts on one page.  I specify a color palette so each data group is associated with the same color in every chart.  I have found that the colors are incorrect in the first chart, but correct in all subsequent charts.  If I rerun the code within the same R session, all the charts have the correct colors.  However, if I exit R and run the code, the first chart again has the wrong colors.

My code is pretty complex, so I put together simple example that illustrates the problem.  Again, the first time I run the code after starting a new R session, the colors are incorrect.  They are correct if the code is rerun within the same R session.

```
# Data vector for bar plot,
#
dvec        <- c(   0,     0,    0,    0,     0,     0,
                    0,     0,    0,    0,     0,     0,
                    0,     0,    0,    0,     0,     0,
                 1.73,     0,    0,    0,     0,     0,
                 4.81,     0,    0, 0.03,  0.03,     0,
                 2.77,     0,    0, 0.42,  1.04,     0,
                 2.84,  0.02,    0, 2.25,  4.21,  0.02,
                 1.32,  0.54, 0.01, 3.44, 10.49,  0.01,
                 0.13,  1.63, 0.02, 4.42, 17.70,  0.03,
                 0.08,  2.49, 0.03, 8.64, 31.07,  0.02,  
                    0,  3.08, 0.05, 9.04, 50.22,  0.01)

# matrix to pass to barplot, 12 columns, 6 rows

smat <- matrix(dvec,nrow=6)                    

# use this color palette and plot the barchart

zoopal <- palette(c("magenta","red","darkred","yellow","cyan","blue"))

barplot(smat,space=0,col=zoopal,axes=FALSE,axisnames=FALSE,
                  xaxs="i",yaxs="i",ann=FALSE)
```

The first time I run the code after starting R, I get this:
[image: Incorrect colors]

When I run the code again, I get this with the correct colors:

[image: Correct colors]

I don't understand why this happens. It is almost as if the palette I specify isn't being used the first time the code is run.  I should note that although I developed the R code using R version 3.2.1 under MacOSX 10.8.5, the same thing happens when the code is run on a colleague's Windows computer.  Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I can reproduce on a current version of R and MacOS. It seems to have something to do with the (unnecessary) call to `palette`. Omitting that call cures the problem. Note that is actually what is described as the expected result from `?palette` which says: "A character vector giving the palette which **was** in effect. " (Emphasis added)

This does seem to me to be a rather non-functional behavior of `palette`. It is apparently designed to act as a system side-effect rather than returning a currently useful value and the value that is returned is presumably supposed to be stored as "oldpal" or some such. As discussed on the help page, the use of palette is supposed to change the mapping of (subsequent) numbers to colors rather than setting, rather than returning a list of colors.

Comment: Thank you.  I missed that in the palette documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `palette()` at all. `barplot` doesn't use it, and you can just specify a vector of colours. Anway, on to the explanation:

There's always a lag via `palette()` when used like this. Storing `x <- palette()` gives the **current** palette not the new one you've just specified. E.g.:

```
oldcols <- c("red","green")
newcols <- c("yellow","blue")
palette(oldcols)
palette()
#[1] "red"   "green"

runone <- palette(newcols)
runone
#[1] "red"   "green"
palette()
#[1] "yellow" "blue"  

runtwo <- palette(oldcols)
runtwo
#[1] "yellow" "blue"  
palette()
#[1] "red"   "green"
```

Comment: Thank you!  I clearly misunderstood how to use palette and was thinking it was similar to color handling routines in other languages I've used.  If I understand you correctly, I can specify "col=c("color1","color2","color3","color4")" in my barplot call.  That is certainly worth knowing (I'm relatively new to R).

Comment: @Fleetboat - yep, just do `zoocol <- c("color1","color2")` and then bung that in the `barplot(..., col=zoocol)`