# R: palette(rainbow()) not being updated for the first attemp

Tags: r, colors, palette

It seems I fail to update colors using the function palette(rainbow()) at the first attempt, but succeed at the second attempt. Are there any smarter way to update the colors, rather than my way to call the function twice?

```
# call the function 
colRainbow = palette(rainbow(3))
colRainbow
# [1] "red"   "green" "blue" 
# success!

# call the function, overwrite the object colRainbow 
colRainbow = palette(rainbow(5))
colRainbow
# [1] "red"   "green" "blue" 
# Fail!

# Re-overwrite the object
colRainbow = palette(rainbow(5))
colRainbow
# [1] "red"     "#CCFF00" "#00FF66" "#0066FF" "#CC00FF"
# success!
```

Comment: Relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734705/colors-incorrect-on-first-execution-of-code/35735749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `palette` says that it returns:

> A character vector giving the palette which *was* in effect

So seeing

```
colRainbow = palette(rainbow(3))
colRainbow = palette(rainbow(5))
colRainbow
# [1] "red"   "green" "blue"
```

is what you should expect, you see the previous palette. Functions that set options in R often work this way, so you can do `old_options = set_options(new_value)`, and then you have the old value stored to restore later.

To see the current palette after each change, just call `palette()` without an argument.